# admob ads for multiple applications android

Tags: android, admob, ads, developer-tools

I could not find anywhere how to tackle multiple applications with ad mob and ad mediation. I currently have 2 applications live and I what to know what is better:

1. to have a single application in the ad providers and use the same id in all applications that I will make
2. Have separate application id for each applications.

What are the ramifications (good and bad) for each option?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered many times before.

You can do either.

To get better targeted ads you should have a unique id for each app.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should definitely have a separate ad id for every app you have. This allows you to better track how your apps perform. It's also intended form admob (and other providers) to do so.